MainDisplayInfoChanged Event Intermittently Firing
I have a .NET MAUI app that I am trying to build out, and I want it to exhibit some behaviours when the orientation changes.
I have added this to the Code Behind of the Content Page, however putting a breakpoint in the Current_MainDisplayInfoChanged method only occasionally gets reached.
I can't work out why?
public partial class Scoreboard : ContentPage
{
    public ScoreboardViewModel VM;

    public Scoreboard(ScoreboardViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VM = vm;
        BindingContext = vm;
        DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfoChanged += Current_MainDisplayInfoChanged;
    }

    private void Current_MainDisplayInfoChanged(object? sender, DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Landscape)
        {
            this.VM.ViewLandscape = true;
            this.VM.ViewPortrait = false;
        }
        else if (e.DisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Portrait)
        {
            this.VM.ViewLandscape = false;
            this.VM.ViewPortrait = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.VM.ViewLandscape = false;
            this.VM.ViewPortrait = true;
        }
    }
}


Looks like you want to use the device orientation to change the layout. You could use the OrientationStateTrigger for this instead of doing that manually. I also wrote a blog post about how to use it.

Does this answer your question? Show different images based on page orientation in .NET MAUI

You can override method OnSizeAllocated on your ContentPage to detect the screen switching between landscape and portrait.
Please refer to the following code:
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        if (height > width) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The screen is portrait ");

            // add your code here

        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The screen is landscape ");

            // add your code here

        }
    }

